# How to click on any button in web application

Tags: python

I want to click on a button in my application. I tried with different locaters please can you guide me about which locater could I used for m sharing you screenshot of the button or inspect element.

[image: 1]

I tried with Xpath and m getting error same showing in ss

[image: 2]

Also tried with find_element(By.Class_Name,"nav-link collapsed")
still facing error in locaters

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: before you execute .click() check whether the element can be located or not. it's either find_element("xpath","") OR find_element(By.XPATH,"") OR find_element_by_xpath(""). In your code, you are writing find_element("By.XPATH","") which have the extra inverted commas